# Why command "screencapture -R0,0,5,5" doesn't creates 5x5 image but creates 10x10 image?

Tags: macos, command-line, screen-capture, osx-yosemite

On Mac OS X Yosemite, following command doesn't creates 5x5 image but creates 10x10 image. Why? I want to take screenshot of 5x5.

```
screencapture -t bmp -R0,0,5,5 ~/Desktop/hogehoge.bmp
```

And here is the properties of the image. It says "Dimensions:10x10". Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may have got a Retina display (if you have got a MacBook Pro Retina or a Retina 27" iMac). This means that an usual pixel is saved as four pixels.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display

Comment: The resolution of the attached screenshot of the info pane shows that he has indeed got a retina display.

Comment: Yes, I'm using retina macbook pro. So I can't take screenshot of 5x5?

Comment: @l'L'l: I tried it. But it created 6x6 image... It seems "screencapture -R<x,y,w,h>"command doesn't support to create image size (2*i-1)x(2*j-1) on retina display mac......

Comment: @Kei you can adjust your scaling factor in System Preferences->Displays (or is it Screens?). You can test if that makes a difference. Note that Mac OS X doesn't allow you to set a 1:1 device pixel ratio for reasons beyond comprehension.

Answer (score -1):

```
very attractive work.
     ( The option -R don't exists  in screencapture)

      Another very simple choice with the options -s -c it's to capture with the mouse and to copy out in the clipboard

     do shell script " /usr/sbin/screencapture -s -c "

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    set frontmost to true
    click menu item "Show Clipboard" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

Comment: This does not look like an answer. What do you mean by "very attractive work"? Have you checked that the -R option does not exist in OS X Yosemite?